# How to avoid polluting scope in angular.js directive that modifies model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think I am polluting my scope but I can't figure out how or how to avoid it:

I have a directive that is called TWICE with different parameters thus:

```
<div profile-summary attributes="user.attributes" sentiment="positive" limit="3" threshold="20"> </div>
<div profile-summary attributes="user.attributes" sentiment="negative" limit="3" threshold="-20"> </div>
```

It prints out a top 3 list of `scope.attributes` sorted asc (if sentiment="positive") or desc (if negative).

This calls a directive thus:

```
app.directive('profileSummary', function () {
    var features;
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            attributes: '=',
            sentiment: '@',
            threshold: '=',
            limit: '='},
        template: '<h5>{{title}}</h5><ol><li ng-repeat="attr in attributes">{{attr.categorical_value}}</li></ol>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //do stuff to

            if (scope.sentiment == 'positive') {
                scope.title = 'Loves';
                features = _.sortBy(scope.attributes, function (f) {
                    return (100000 - f.reactivity)
                });
                features = _.filter(features, function (f) {
                    return f.reactivity > scope.threshold
                });
            } else {
                scope.title = 'Hates';
                features = _.sortBy(scope.attributes, function (f) {
                    return (f.reactivity)
                });
                features = _.filter(features, function (f) {
                    return f.reactivity < scope.threshold
                });
            }
            features.length = scope.limit;


            scope.attributes = features; //am I polluting global scope? how to avoid?
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the second directive duplicates the output of the first. If I remove the first directive, I am getting the correct (different) output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way i can think of to fix it would be to use the `features` array in you directive template instead of attributes array. This way attributes array would not be touched

```
  template: '<h5>{{title}}</h5><ol><li ng-repeat="attr in features">{{attr.categorical_value}}</li></ol>',
```

Now features should be defined on the directive scope like this

`scope.features = _.sortBy(scope.attributes, function (f) {`

So this is not required

`scope.attributes = features;  //delete`